# CustomView - Clear canvas thanks to setImageResource 0

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view

I tried to clear the current image of a **custom** ImageView programmatically, after I called the method setImageResource(), my custom image view keep the old image. I try the following solutions :

- canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,Mode.CLEAR)
- draw an empty bitmap, nothing happened...

Here is the onDraw method of my view :

```
private void loadBitmap() {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable();
    image = (bitmapDrawable != null) ? bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() : null;
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    loadBitmap();
    final int circleCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    final int radius = circleCenter - 5;

    if (image != null) {
        paint.setShader(computeBitmapShader());
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter, circleCenter, radius, paint);
    } else {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake from my part. I was using an animation where a View was supposed to come on my CircleView and after dissapear but the setFillAfter false didn't work...